# is it possible to specify a constant image size in a swift/Xcode tableview? If so, how would I do this?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, image-resizing

I am trying to set up a `TableView` that is searchable. I want the display to show a company name, a date, and their logo. I have this working in my code; however, all of my logos are different sizes, therefore, my interface looks very sloppy. Can I set a uniform size to each image in the table view? Similar to Instagram's search page.

I tried using:

```
cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(data:self.filteredCakes[indexPath.row].imageName, scale: CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40))
```

However, I was presented with the error:

> "Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Data'"

The variable `imageName` is a string associated with images in my assets folder

This is my code that functions but presents me with varying image sizes:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell     {
    let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style:                         UITableViewCell.CellStyle.subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

        cell.textLabel?.text = self.filteredCakes[indexPath.row].businessName
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = self.filteredCakes[indexPath.row].dateText
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named:self.filteredCakes[indexPath.row].imageName)

        return cell
}
```

I expect the images to be a uniform size while still displaying the companies logo properly. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Set height and width constraints on the image view. Then set its `contentMode` to `UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFit`.

Comment: How would I set the height and width constraints on the image view?

Comment: You may need to create a custom UITableViewCell to do this.